# activate jre7 on solaris 10

Tags: solaris, java, solaris-10

I installed jre7 on solaris 10 at the location /usr/jre7.

jdk1.5 and jre is already there at /usr/java

I want jre7 to run instead of jre5. how can I do that?

and also how do I find out which version of jre is currently active?

my questions:

1) How can I find out which is the current JRE version being considered?

2) How can I change it to JRE7

Answer (score 1):

This is basic, How do I set up my environment questions.  They are not specific to Java as such.

> How can I find out which is the current JRE version being considered?

```
which java
```

Like any other command.  If you are not sure what version this is you can run

```
java -version
```

> How can I change it to JRE7

On Windows and UNIX, your `PATH` determines the directories it searches to find an executable.

You need to change your path so the desired version in on your path before any version you don't want.